How to show the parametrizations are for the same curve?
For a parametrization of a curve $\gamma_1: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and $\sigma(s)$ is a bijection from $[c,d]$ to $[a,b]$, now if I composite of them as $\gamma_1 \circ \sigma$, I get another parametrization. My question may be a little silly but I can not convince myself confidently why these two parametrizations define the same curve? How to show that?

Suggestion: First clarify (for yourself) the meaning of same curve (same set of points as images? same orientation/direction of traversal? same as mappings?). Then at least there is a careful definition to work from.

Yes. You do give me a nice starting point. With that, I can clearly show that these two parametrizations define the same curve (same sets of points as images.) This holds if $\sigma$ is a bijection.

Please feel free to write up an answer yourself!

As mentioned in the comments, it all depends on your notion of "same curve". In your case, I would argue that they are the same if the bijection $\sigma$ is actually a orientation-preserving diffeomorphism. It is often denoted as $\phi$ in this context.
Some reasoning:

A bijection is keeping the trace/image $\gamma(I)$ invariant. But it might do so in a very disorderly way. To me, the continuity is a defining property of any reasonable path, especially in $\mathbb C$. So you need your $\sigma$ to be bijective as well.
Take for example the unit circle with its two possible directions as paths. Clearly they have the same trace. And there is even a cont. bijection between them. Yet, in most branches of mathematics, they are treated as different paths. This is because the derivative of $\sigma$ is not always $>0$ (or was the condition $\geq$? not sure..). This leads to the reversion of the orientation of the paths. Your bijection needs to be a orientation-preserving one. That is why you need it to be a orientation-preserving (i.e. $\phi'>0$) diffeomorphism.

